# Is it possible to move cshtml pages to a library project and host them from another web app?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

We develop Microsoft Web API applications, and we have a lot of custom code in our help doc generator / help pages.  It has to be cut and paste into new projects, and is always at risk of being trashed by nuget updates which affect the help doc files.  So we want to put this in a library.

Obviously the extension methods and help page model objects could be put into a class library, but that still leaves the cshtml files.  I had the idea of why not just take a copy of a whole Web API project with our modified help doc pages and turn that into a library.  You'd have your main project with the Web API but it would need to host cshtml pages from the library to display the help pages.  Is this possible, and how would you do it?